# Click on spam with Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, checkbox, webdriver

I want to click on the checkbox from the Google ReCAPTCHA-test. For that (I think) I have to click on the following span:

```
<span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label"><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation"><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner-overlay"></div></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div></span>
```

https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/ Here the website is (it's just an empty website with an ReCAPTCHA in it).

I am using the latest version of the Chrome driver and it's defined as driver. I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("span").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]').click()

driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-anchor').click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name('recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox').click()
```

but i'm always getting following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {*this is every try different*}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

I'm very new at Python and it's my first try with Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox is in an iframe so you need to use selenium to switch to that first. Below should help you click the check box, and also allow you to get to the 9 boxes.

First ensure you have the following imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Next:

```
# Switch to iframe to click the checkbox
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".g-recaptcha>div>div>iframe")))

#click the checkbox
driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-anchor').click()

#switch back to the main content in order to switch to the next iframe we need
driver.switch_to.default_content()

#switch to the iframe that contains the 9 boxes
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='recaptcha challenge']")))

#get the 9 boxes
boxes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#rc-imageselect-target button')
```